# Callback Hell - Node.js deal with loops that contain async functions

Tags: node.js, callback

Let's say we have the following pseudo code:

```
    forLoop() {
        forLoop() {
            asyncFunction() {
                return of AsyncFunction
            }
            asyncFunction() {
                return of AsyncFunction
            }
        }
    }
//Execute this part when all asyncs are done from previous loops.
```

I know this is not valid code but how would this be handled in Node.js

Comment: promise would help you. For your answer `promise.all`

Comment: Yeah, if you just want to kick off a load of async actions and then do something when they've all completed, `Promise.all` is the way to go.

Comment: have a look at async.js

Comment: For a real answer, you would have to show us real code.  Async functions are non-blocking in node.js so all the loop does is start a whole bunch of async operations, it doesn't sequence them or wait for them.  If you want them sequenced (run A, wait for A to finish, then run B, etc...), you can't use a plain loop like this.  Please show us your actual problem with real code as an appropriate solution depends upon specific details in the real code.  This question as written cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use async package, this package has async.forEach method which can be used here.

```
async.forEach(Object.keys(dataObj), function (item, callback){ 
    console.log(item); // print the key

    // tell async that that particular element of the iterator is done
    callback(); 

}, function(err) {
    console.log('iterating done');
});
```

You can have async foreach loop within an async foreach loop.